# how to install DotNetNuke_Community_05.02.00_Source

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, installation, dotnetnuke

Please let me know how to install and run DotNetNuke_Community_05.02.00_Source.zip in visual studio 2008.

I keepp getting all kinds of errors

Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors are you getting - that might help

Answer (score 1):

- Extract the zip file to a target directory.
- Create a new IIS website.
- If you are using Win 2k3 Add `Read, Write, Modify` to the `Network Service` group in the security tab of the target directory.(`ASP.NET` group in Win XP)
- Change the `Release.config` in the root of application to `web.config`.
- Create a new database and change the connection string in the `web.config`.
- Run the website and install DNN.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post has some good info -

http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2009/03/dotnetnuke-installing-dnn-5-with-vs.html

Might help if you detailed the errors